# Enable button if textbox populated

Tags: c#

I have tried to code a button such that it is disabled upon form loading however enabled once a textbox has had text entered. My code is below, which is probably familiar:

```
Public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.enabled = false;
}

private void textbox_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text);
}
```

The button indeed loads up disabled, the enabling function doesn't work upon text input and I'm not sure what the issue could be. It is a modal form is that matters. I was wondering if maybe I needed an event listener (although I'm not certain how exactly they work).

Comment: Place a break point in the line where you set button1's Enabled property. See if the event is fired correctly. If it's not fired, you might miss setting the event handler in your designer.

Comment: did this line `button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text);` throw any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Designer.cs file and make sure you have event handler registration there. Something like this:

```
this.textBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. I tried to add the handler registration but I got the error "Form does not contain a definition for...". For what it's worth, I managed to add an event handler to a different textbox and the button enabling feature worked perfectly there.

Comment: Apologies, that was a stupid mistake on my part...I hadn't declared the textbox_TextChanged event in the first place. All working now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Will this work? I can't really see a problem with your code though...

```
button1.Enabled = textbox.Text != "";
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the solution to your problem, but this would be the fastest check for one's computer to perform (at least if you let the JIT compiler optimize your code):

```
button1.Enabled = textbox.Text.Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of the following on the `TextChanged` property of the `TextBox` :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (textbox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
        button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

or, using the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
        button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

The the below line:

```
button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text);
```

If it didn't work for you or if you are getting an error, then probably because the [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method was introduced in **.NET 4**